# run one test by name from one nodeunit file

Tags: nodeunit

Is it possible to run only one test from nodeunit test file with several tests. My `tests.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
    test2: function (test) {
        console.log ("test2")
        test.done();
    },
    test1: function (test) {
        console.log ("test1")
        test.done();
    }
};
```

I can run all tests:

```
$ nodeunit tests.js
```

But I want to run only test2 like:

```
$ nodeunit tests.js test2
```

Is it possible without spliting file `tests.js` into 2 separate files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See *nodeunit -h* for the available options (This is for version 0.8.1):

```
Usage: nodeunit [options] testmodule1.js testfolder [...]
Options:

  --config FILE     the path to a JSON file with options
  --reporter FILE   optional path to a reporter file to customize the output
  --list-reporters  list available build-in reporters
  -t name,          specify a test to run
  -f fullname,      specify a specific test to run. fullname is built so: "outerGroup - .. - innerGroup - testName"
  -h, --help        display this help and exit
  -v, --version     output version information and exit
```

So from that the following should do what you want:

```
$ nodeunit tests.js -t test2
```

e.g:

```
$ nodeunit ./tests.js -t test2

tests.js
test2
✔ test2
```